# Creating comboboxes in loop VBA

Tags: vba

Hey guys I want to create a certain amount of combo boxes when a commandbutton is pressed. I cant figure out how to do it so I will really appreciate your help. This is the code ive created:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim AttPoints As Integer, Result As String
    Range("E1:Z4").ClearContents
    AttPoints = Range("B2").Value

    If AttPoints = 0 Then
        Result = "You have selected 0 AttPoints!"

    ElseIf AttPoints < 0 Then
        Result = "You have selected a negative amount of AttPoints!"

    ElseIf AttPoints > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 5 To (AttPoints + 4)
        Cells(1, i).Value = "Attachment point:" & (i - 4)
        Next i

    End If
    Range("A1") = Result
End Sub
```

In the for loop I create a row of cells in which the text attachment point is placed. 
Under these texts i want the same amount of comboboxes as can be seen in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following bit of code inside your loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ...

    Shapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Forms.Combobox.1", _
    Left:=Cells(2, i).Left, Top:=Cells(2, i).Top, _
    Width:=Cells(2, i).Width, Height:=Cells(2, i).Height * 2

    ...

End Sub
```

That should produce your desired result.

Comment: Thanks! I should also include the Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() part?

Comment: No, you only need to include the 3 lines in the middle inside your loop obviously. Please accept the answer above as solution if your problem is solved.